# C++ CORBA DII issues

Tags: c++, corba, tao

Could all those CORBA experts out there please help me with this one.

I have a multithreaded application with some code that sends a message to a server and waits for a response back. I can see that the server is sending the response back however the application doesnt seem to receive it.

Heres part of my code.

```
  // Create a request object for the given message
  msg.request = serverRef->_request("receiveCoreMessageVia");
  msg.request->set_return_type (CORBA::_tc_short);

  msg.request->add_in_arg() <<= msg.sourceGateway;
  msg.request->add_in_arg() <<= msg.octetSeq;

  msg.request->send_deferred();

  ...
  // The following code is in a while loop in a different function. It uses the request reference to check the response.
  // Check if the request has completed
  if (!msg->request->poll_response())
  {
    clssendlog << debug << "Polling..." << endl;

    return false; // No response yet
  }

  // Get the returned result
  clssendlog << debug << "Get response..." << endl;
  msg->request->get_response();

  clssendlog << debug << "Reading the returned response value" << endl;
  CORBA::Short tmp = 0;
  msg->request->return_value () >>= tmp;
```

The result is that it keeps saying Polling even if the server responds.
This is a basic DII invocation and I am actually testing the code on ACE/TAO 5.7.9. This exact code works perfectly on omniORB 4.1.4. However, I really want this to work on ACE/TAO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix by changing object reference from _ptr to _var. I wrote a small test application to verify this. After changing the pointer type its behaving as expected serving the responses. So the problem was getting the initial reference to the interface.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about this but it appears to me that you will *exit* this function if the first poll response fails. Then, when you come back in, you'll send *another* message (with the `send_deferred()` call), independent from the first.

That means that, unless you strike it lucky and a response appears before you call `poll_response()`, you'll always get a polling message.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying it but ive just added a comment to the code.That particular polling sits in a separate function in a while loop. So it always loops checking for the response. As I mentioned above you will see "Polling..." output continuously on TAO where as on omniORB it will return immediately.

Comment: No probs, @kuzyt, I'll make it CW since it's not that helpful but I'll leave it here for the record.